# error: "'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'" in predicting y using curve function in r for logistic regression

Tags: r, shiny, logistic-regression

I am getting the following error: "'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'"

I used the curve function with a binomial regression model to mimic a relationship. That part works fine.

I'm trying to use the same curve function to estimate y given a specific x. This is where I am having trouble and getting the error above.

I know the error is coming from the line `curve(predict(model1, data.frame(X=XInput)))` below. If I take curve function out, the code will run but does not give me a y value on the curve function.

See all of the sample code below and please advise.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


data<-data.frame(datasource)

...


model1pred <- reactive({

XInput <- input$B/input$C
curve(predict(model1, data.frame(X=XInput)))})

...

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

XInput <- input$B/input$C

plot(data$X, data$Y, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", bty = "n", pch = 16)

if(input$condition){
  model1 <- glm(X ~ Y, family = binomial, data = subset(data, condition==1))
} else {
  model1 <- glm(X ~ Y, family = binomial, data = subset(data, condition==0))
}
curve(predict(model1, data.frame(X=XInput), "resp"), add=TRUE)

})

output$pred1 <- renderText({
model1pred()
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem by setting the `xname` variable. This has a default value of x so it searches for that. If you change your code to the following:

```
curve(predict(model1, data.frame(X=XInput)), xname="model1")
```

then it'll work.